# Is there a common lisp library for creating excel spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, common-lisp

Is there a common lisp library for creating excel spreadsheets? I'd much much prefer that it output one of the XML formats.

Update:

To add some more context, creating a csv file from common lisp is pretty trivial, and that's what I'm doing now.

The *[XML Spreadsheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example)* format is pretty simple, and there are common lisp libraries that make it easy to output arbitrary XML, so rolling my own would be pretty easy, but if something already exists to ease the process I would prefer that.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but there is a java library for outputting excel http://poi.apache.org that you could interact with from Clojure.

Answer (score 3):

[buildnode](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/buildnode) seems to be what you want. It lacks documentation, but includes a basic working example of an Excel spreadsheet.

It's also quicklisp-installable, so easy to start playing with.

```
(ql:quickload 'buildnode-excel)...
```

I'm just leaving this here, because I almost decided to write my own Excel generator before discovering buildnode.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but the xml-emitter library looks useful. It ought to be trivial to get the generated XML into Excel, or any spreadsheet.

http://www.cliki.net/xml-emitter

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like this doesn't quite solve the problem, but it does provide a useful starting point for rolling an Excel-XML library, so up-voting.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you will have to output CSV files and import them into Excel.  If you need more than just data, Lisp might not be the best tool...
You could automate Excel to do it via COM interface, but a quick search doesn't find a COM binding for Lisp.  I know one (used to) exists for Scheme though.

Comment: down-voting because this answer seems to miss some important points in the question (most notably that an XML format is desired, which could surely be done without involving (or even having access to) COM/Excel automation).